# XText: CrossReference does not find reference

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

I have the following, minimal example:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    (classes += Class)+
;

Class:
    'class' id=ID ('extends' extendclass = [Class])? '{'  
'}'
;
```

And the following model....

```
class A{}
class B extends A{

}
```

However this does not work and says "Couldn't resolve reference to Class 'A'". Anyone knows why?

Comment: Is this related to java ?

Comment: I think so, since Xtend+Xtext is used for Java Projects...

Comment: can you elaborate what you are exactly doing? how do you call the serializer? how do you create the resource/resourceset?

Comment: do you have build automatically on and does the project have xtext nature?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your attribute `id` from `Class` is not recognized for naming, just change `id` for `name`:

```
 Model:
    (classes += Class)+
;


Class:
    'class' name=ID ('extends' extendclass = [Class | ID])? '{'  
'}'
```